# Validate IGN Error

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

No error message, just not working...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function validign {
var validign= /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/;
if (validign<1) {
    alert("Not a valid IGN!");
    return false;
}
}
</script>
```

ign stands for in game name. the function is later being called upon by a form using onsubmit.

random questions: Is there a way to not do onsubmit and have it be done while the person is typing? or does that require ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your syntax is *very* wrong. You need something to test it against. So maybe:

```
function validign() {
    var validign = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/;

    if(!validign.test(document.getElementById('myIGNBox').value)) {
        alert("Not a valid IGN!");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

As for doing it while the person is typing: yes. You can use a variety of events. I prefer `input` and `keyup`. [Here's a quick and simple demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/TvRsd/)

Comment: I'm confused out of my mind. I barely eever use javascript. First what parameters should be put in the validign function? Second, what is validign.test? What is test?

Comment: @Depetrify: Did you or did you not write that regular expression? `test` is what you use to test a string against a regular expression. And no parameters are necessary, just replace `myIGNBox` with the ID of your IGN box.

Comment: i wrote my first shitty one, never used test. lol. so test is like filter_var in PHP?

Comment: sooo wait.. on the demo you made, where is it getting told what form to test? Ignbox is just where it outputs right?

Comment: @Depetrify: No, it gets its value too. You could try [learning JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) :)